# OOP on php, objects behaivor based on session

Tags: php, oop, session

I do need some help with class definition

I am beginning a PHP 7.0 project, if you are not a php guru but have experience with oop I am sure you also could help.

I have the following classes that helps to build a HTML page

```
interface PageBuilderInterface
{
    public function getHTMLPage(): string;
    public function getHead(): string;
    public function getBody(): string;
    public function getMenu(): string;
    public function getMainArea(): string;
    public function getFooter(): string;
}



class PageBuilder implements PageBuilderInterface
{

    public function getHTMLPage(): string
    {
        return "<!doctype html><html>" .
                    $this->getHead() .
                    $this->getBody() 
               "</html>";
    }

    public function getHead(): string
    {
        return '<meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Page Title</title>';
    }


    public function getBody(): string
    {
        return "<body>" . 
                    $this->getMenu() .
                    $this->getMainArea() .
                    $this->getFooter() .
               "</body>";
    }

    public function getMenu(): string
    {
        return '<a href="index.php">Home</a> | 
                <a href="login.php">Login</a>  | 
                <a href="register.php">Become Member</a> ';
    }

    public function getMainArea(): string
    {
        return '<h1>Main Content Here</h1>
                <p>Loren Ipsun...</p>';
    }

    public function getFooter(): string
    {
        return '<div>Footer Page Here</div>';
    }
}
```

usage:

```
$page = new PageBuilder();
echo $page->getHTMLPage();
```

It is simple and works.

Now, I have the a new requirement: some methos should work quite different according User on session, as example say we have "Guest", "Basic Member" and "Golden Member" user types.

Links on main menu are different for each type of member, and should be able to show different info for each member (like messages, credits, balance or any other info)

so,

PageBuilder::getMenu()

should returns some links like

Home | Login | Become a Member   for visitor
Home | Messages | Logout   for basic members
Home | Messages | Balance $ 208.23 | Logout    for golder members

on future I could need more "user types" and different links for them, that is way this should be easy to change on the future.

I know: I DO need to get User status inside getMenu() method, but not sure wich of the following options is the best:

1 - create user from session

```
public function getMenu(): string
{
    $user = new User($_SESSION['id_user']);
    $links = $user->getLinks(); // perhaps an array with links

    return doSomeFormatToLinks($links);
}
```

2 - global user object

```
public function getMenu(): string
{   global $user;
    $links = $user->getLinks();

/* .... build html links here */  
}
```

3 - as parameter

```
public function getMenu(User $user): string
{   
    $links = $user->getLinks();   
}
```

4 - user object as class attibute setting it with constructor

```
class PageBuilder implements PageBuilderInterface
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user
    }  
}
```

5 - similar than 4 but with setter

```
class PageBuilder implements PageBuilderInterface
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = $user
    }

    public function setUser($this->user = $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }  
}
```

6 - other options?

I am looking for the best option, paying attention to SOLID principles and looking to desing it in the way it is easy to mock and test with phpunit, trying to separate "user" login from "pagebuilder" logic as much as possible

options 1 and 2: I have bad feeling about them, they use global status, it is smelt, isn´t it?
option 3: I find it easy to test.
options 4 and 5: I think is good idea to have User as an attibute, since I could use user status for other methods on the class, but on the other hand I am worried about it´s semanting, I am telling that a user is belongs to a pagebuilder...
option 6: I am sure your suggestion will be the best :D

thanks for your time!

Comment: Using a class to build html is not really good practice these days. Have you considered using a modern framework? They do much of this out of the box, so you can concentrate on your website code.

Answer (score -1):

So as always all depends on what level of flexibility and controll you want to archive.

But you can definitely exclude point 1 and point 2 as an valid solutions.

Both elements are risky to use because you do not have any control of those data. Anyone at anytime can change those data and you will end up with generated code for the wrong user. Or something event worst would happened.

On the other side you have mentioned two types of inverse control pattern and actaully you can use both of them. So lets distinguish when you should use which solution.

4. This is a nice approach and it is called conif you plan to have one element per page because if you want to change something you need to create new object with new user value. But it should be the most used approach for elements that you need to create once on the application lifetime.
5. This is setter injection and this is also an good solution but in my opinion we should avoid this one, why? Because you need always keep in mind that if you need to call some method you need first to call the set method. If you will not call it you can get strange results, at least you can mix this with constructor injection and only use setter injection when you really need to change this. There are also some other usages but keep it clean.
6. It is the most elastic approach when it came to calling it, but you need the user object in all places where you want to call this method. This approach has also pros and cons. From one side you have nice, one place approach that is solving some issue that are not able to be solved with setter injections. You don't need to think about any other method to be called you just need to give this method all the parameters that it is expecting, and you can generate with one object menus for all you users (I don not think that this is real life solution in this case). And on the other you can not set up this object for one user and send menu object to other places to just generate it. You always will need to call it also the User object.

So each approach is good for the 3,4,5 but each is solving some other cases. In my opinion for this specific case I would go with the constructor injection.

```
class PageBuilder implements PageBuilderInterface
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user
    }  

    public function getMenu(User $user): string
    {   
        return $user->getLinks();   
    }
```

}

I hope this will help to understand those differences.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct in your feelings that options #1 and #2 are not what you're looking for. Any object you create that uses global variables immediately violates the encapsulation principle, and will make your code unnecessarily more difficult to test.

#1

This is particularly problematic as it is instantiating a new `User` object directly within the function, which will make it impossible to mock with PHPUnit. Sometimes creating a new object can be desirable behaviour, but it's very dependant on the semantics of what your class is doing. Since you are writing a `PageBuilder` class, it seems very unlikely that it should also be it's job to know how to create new `User` object from scratch. That responsibility should fall to something else that is dedicated to that task, such as some kind of `UserService` class, which you can then use whenever you need to create/get a `User` object. That way if you ever change how a `User` object is constructed, such as requiring it to have an extra construction parameter, the only place you should have to update is your `UserService` class rather than all over application.

#2

By writing code in this way, you are hiding away the fact that your function requires there to be an already defined `$user` variable. Even if someone did go into the code of your function to see that it's needed, they would also have to somehow know or workout what object type that variable is meant to hold. Presuming that you use some kind of IDE to develop your code in (and you really should), your IDE will have no idea that you potentially called that function somewhere without defining `$user` first. This takes away one of the most basic and powerful tools that your IDE can provide in helping to reduce basic code errors.

#3

Whether or not this is the best option really depends on the exact usage scenarios and semantics of your code, but, I would say in most cases this is the style you will want to write in.

The advantages of this approach include:

- Ability to take advantage of PHPUnit mock objects during tests
- The requirements of your function are made perfectly clear to anyone attempting to use/understand it
- Your `PageBuilder` object is re-usable for multiple `User`s

What I mean by that final point is that you can use the same `PageBuilder` object for as many `User` objects as you like. Supposed there was a scenario where you wanted to loop through every User in the system and produce some output based on each one. Using this approach would potentially allow you to do the following:

```
$pageBuilder = new PageBuilder();
$pageContent = '';

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $pageContent .= $pageBuilder->getUserContent($user);
}

echo $pageContent;
```

The alternative if you went with #4 would be something like:

```
$pageContent = '';

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $pageBuilder = new PageBuilder($user);
    $pageContent .= $pageBuilder->getUserContent();
}

echo $pageContent;
```

While the overhead of creating a new `PageBuilder`object may not be particularly high in this case, the pattern is generally worse and will create extra overhead regardless. And if your `PageBuilder` object happened to have a heavy constructor (maybe one day you need to change it so that it requires data from a database before it's ready), then you could suffer a reasonable performance hit.

#4

You would only use this approach if you had some particular need for the `PageBuilder` object and the `User` object to become tightly bound together. In that scenario, this approach would be more correct than #5 **IF** you were designing your `PageBuilder` class in such a way that none of it's public functions would work without a `User` first being set **AND** you didn't want it to be possible for any other `User` object to become set on it instead i.e. exactly 1 `PageBuilder` per `User`. Since the overall impression I am getting is that your `PageBuilder` is pretty stateless (i.e. it has no need to track data across multiple function calls or retain a memory of what it's done), this doesn't seem like a restriction you should be imposing on yourself for the future.

#5

As inversely stated above, you would prefer this to #4 if you wanted to tightly bind a `User` to a `PageBuilder` for a limited duration, but then be able to bind a different `User` at a later date. This makes it quite similar to the example given in #3.

```
$pageContent = '';
$pageBuilder = new PageBuilder();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $pageBuilder->setUser($user);
    $pageContent .= $pageBuilder->getUserContent();
}

echo $pageContent;
```

This would be entirely dependant on your use case, but in your given situation I would say it is still inferior to #3 if you don't require the ability to internally track data between multiple function calls.

**TLDR**: #1 and #2 are bad, hard to understand from the outside, hard to test, and hard to maintain. #3, #4 and #5 are all testable and potentially viable depending your overall application structure and logic, but generally speaking the pattern of #3 is the most flexible.